# Perl regex match string not ending in something

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

What regex will match this correctly, please?

I want to identify strings that do not end in specific text (_array).  I've tried to use negative lookahead, but I can't get it working.  (Note the obvious answer is to do the inverse (m{_array$}), but there's a reason I don't want to do that).

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 while(<DATA>) {
    #
    ## If the string does not end with '_array' print No, otherwise print Yes
    m{(?!_array)$} ? print "No  = " : print "Yes = ";
    print;
 }
 __DATA__
 chris
 hello_world_array
 another_example_array
 not_this_one
 hello_world
```

My wanted output should be:

```
 No  = chris
 Yes = hello_world_array
 Yes = another_example_array
 No  = not_this_one
 No  = hello_world
```

Comment: reverse it? if it does end in '_array$' print "Yes", otherwise print "No" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need negative look *behind*. I.e., you want to search for the end of the string not preceded `_array`.

Note that you need to `chomp` the line first, as `$` will match both before and after a trailing newline.

And the conditional operator is meant to return a *value* - it is not a shorthand for an `if` statement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  # If the string does not end with '_array' print No, otherwise print Yes
  print /(?<!_array)$/ ? "No  = $_\n" : "Yes = $_\n";
}

__DATA__
chris
hello_world_array
another_example_array
not_this_one
hello_world
```

**Output**

```
No  = chris
Yes = hello_world_array
Yes = another_example_array
No  = not_this_one
No  = hello_world
```

Comment: +1 For identifying the chomp problem. The "do what I mean" functionality of `$` does not quite work with negative lookbehinds there. The specific ending required (without chomp) would seem to be `\n\z`. Not sure which is better, to chomp or handle any line ending.

Comment: I generally prefer `s/\s+\z//` to `chomp` as there's always the chance of invisible trailing whitespace messing things up further. Nandling any possible line ending in the regular expression isn't so easy: you can't write either `/(?<!_array\n)\z/` because that is a variable-length look-behind, or `/(?<!_array)\n*\z/` because it has the same problem as `$`. And `/(?<!_array)\n\z/` won't work if the last line of the file is missing a newline. So I go for `chomp`.

Comment: Thanks Borodin for the answer.  I enjoy posting questions here as you generally receive many more learning points than the initial question asked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;   # Remove linefeed
    #
    ## If the string does not end with '_array' print No, otherwise print Yes
    m{(?<!_array)$} ? print "No  = " : print "Yes = ";
    say;
}
```

**Output:**

```
No  =  chris
Yes =  hello_world_array
Yes =  another_example_array
No  =  not_this_one
No  =  hello_world
```